# How to add tracking number column to order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid

How to add tracking number column to order grid?

I tried with this code but doesn't work

```
$this->addColumn('tracking', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('tracking'),
            'index' => 'tracking',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->getTrackingNumbers(),
        ));
```

Any ideas please..

Update:

By the way i edit on sales `grid.php` to add this code

```
$collection->getSelect()
        ->from(
            array(),
            array(
                'track_number' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(
                    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`t`.`track_number` SEPARATOR ",")
                    FROM `bg8_sales_flat_shipment_track` as `t`
                    WHERE `main_table`.`entity_id` = `t`.`order_id`
                )'),
            )
        );
```

Its working fine but the filter not working i tried to add public & protected function and its freezing when i add value to search on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ***add tracking no at sales grid*** then you need to add `sales_flat_shipment_track` table with `sales grid order collection table`.

Order **may have multiple tracking no.** ,So you need to follow [Atwix blog](https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-sku-column-to-orders-grid/)
 in order to implement your requirement.

**add below to observer class**

```
$select->joinLeft('sales_flat_shipment_track', 'sales_flat_shipment_track.order_id = main_table.entity_id', 
        array('trackingno' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_shipment_track.track_numberSEPARATOR ", ")')));
$select->group(‘main_table.entity_id');
```

Just add the following code to our layout e**xtendedgrid.xml:**

> ```
> <action method="addColumnAfter">
>     <columnId>trackingno</columnId>
>     <arguments>
>         <header>Tracking no</header>
>         <index>trackingno</index>
>         <type>text</type>
>     </arguments>
> </action>
> ```

Now.change

```
<action method="addColumnAfter">
    <columnId>trackingno</columnId>
    <arguments helper="atwix_extendedgrid/getTrackingnoColumnParams"/>

</action>
```

at helper class:

```
public function getTrackingnoColumnParams()
{
    return array(
        'header' => 'Tracking no',
        'index' => 'trackingno',
        'type' => 'text',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array('Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer', 'filtertrackingno'),
    );
}
```

**then at filtertrackingno**

```
public function filtertrackingno($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $collection->getSelect()->having(
        "group_concat(sales_flat_shipment_track.track_number SEPARATOR ', ') like ?", "%$value%");

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @amit-bera for sharing this with me. Can you please which files should i edit. I am sorry i'm new with Magento. I updated the post please check out it.